# Disable OpenType `ccmp` Glyph Composition in CSS

Tags: css, fonts, electron, opentype

I'm using a font called [Lora](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lora?query=Lora&preview.text=mysterious%20%60accent%60&preview.text_type=custom) in an Electron app, and I encountered a problem where text like `` mysterious `accent` `` is automatically converted to `mysterious àccent` due to OpenType [glyph composition](https://helpx.adobe.com/fonts/using/open-type-syntax.html#ccmp).

```html
<p>mysterious `accent`</p>
```

becomes:

[image: glyph composition]

I tried disabling this feature using [`font-feature-settings: "ccmp" off`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings), but no luck.  This is happening inside of an Electron app, but I'm strangely unable to reproduce it on e.g. the [Google Fonts page](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lora?query=Lora&preview.text=mysterious%20%60accent%60&preview.text_type=custom) in Chrome.

How can I correctly disable the `ccmp` OpenType feature in Electron?

Comment: The immediately solution would of course be "don't abuse accents by using them as quote symbols, just use real quotes instead". That said: did you load the font in a font editor? Is this _actually_ ccmp? Because if I load Lora in Font Creator and look at its opentype features, `ccmp` is not involved here. There is an `aalt` rule, but it does not do what you're showing.

Comment: Unfortunately that ship has sailed and the standalone ` is part of the syntax of many programming languages.

Comment: Then please update your post to show the _actual_ problem string, because what your post is currently showing off is natural text rather than programming text (and natural text never uses grave as quotation), even if the bug has been fixed since, because SO posts are forever =)

Comment: Could you clarify the type of edit you'd like to see?  On English keyboards it is perfectly possible to type ` as a standalone character, and it's done very frequently in e.g. Markdown documents to delimit natural-language phrases.  That's exactly where my example comes from -- the screenshot is taken from a WYSIWYG markdown editor where the font is set to Lora.

Comment: Perhaps changing the title of the question is better?  Lora's creator originally told me it was an issue with `ccmp` before discovering the bug.  So really, my question has nothing to do with CSS or glyph composition at all.  In that sense, I do agree this question/answer will not be helpful to people who land on this question from a Google search.

Comment: In markdown, the backtick is a code delimiter, and your markdown editor or parser will never give your the "real text" combination of backtick + anything because it'll have switched to code mode for what follows. In a plain text editor that has no idea what markdown is, different story of course, but then in that case mention that, and also show the exact use-case that triggered it. Or of course alternatively, if this was a transient issue no one will ever run into again in the future, deleting the post would also make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a [bug with the font](https://github.com/cyrealtype/Lora-Cyrillic/issues/55#event-6479992016), and has since been fixed in the latest release.